# How to write update query using linq to sql in where condition having two column names in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I want to update one column in sql.in where condition two column names are there.

below is mu update query:

```
  string sql = "UPDATE contact set ContactName=@ContactName where ContactID=@ContactId AND UserID=@Userid";
```

now I want to write using linq.How to write above query using linq.please help me.I tried

```
  var updatequery = (from x in obj.Contacts where x.ContactID == ContactID select x).First();

                  updatequery.ContactName = ContactName;
                  obj.SubmitChanges();
```

but in the above query where condition having only one column name.I want to where condition having two column names.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `&& SecondColumn == secondValue`

Comment: @TimSchmelter thank you

Comment: And of course, never write SQL like that - *always* use parameterized SQL instead of putting values directly into the SQL itself.

Answer (score 3):

You just have to use the [conditional-AND operator `&&`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx):

```
var updateContacts = from x in obj.Contacts 
                  where x.ContactID == ContactID && x.SecondColumn == SecondValue 
                  select x;

// now use First or a loop if you expect multiple
foreach(var contact in updateContacts)
    contact.ContactName = ContactName;
obj.SubmitChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know if this will help but you can try this as well.

```
var updatequery = obj.Contacts
              .Where(x => x.ContactID == ContactID && x.SecondColumn == SecondValue)
              .FirstOrDefault();
updatequery.ContactName = ContactName;
obj.SubmitChanges();
```